# How to use Twilio Proxy with one participant communicating from Node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio

New to twilio and Node.js

I am trying to build something very similar to Twilio Proxy except I have one participant that is already communicating in Node.js

In other words, Participant A sends a message with Node.js, Twilio Proxy sends SMS to Participant B. Participant B replies with SMS, and participant A receives the response in Node.js.

Is this possible using Twilio Proxy? If so, which Docs can I read to understand how I might build this?

**Relevant Docs:**

- [Using Proxy with Channels](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/channels)
- [JavaScript Programmable Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/javascript/quickstart)
- [Twilio Proxy: Participants](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/api/participant)
- [Twilio Proxy: Sending Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/api/sending-messages)